# P-groups and homomorphisms...

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-groups

If $f: G \rightarrow H$ is a surjective homomorphism, $G$ finite, prove the following:

1) If $P$ is a p-subgroup of $G$, then $f(P)$ is a p-subgroup of $H$.

2) If $S$ is a Sylow-p-subgroup of $G$, then then $f(S)$ is a Sylow-p-subgroup of $H$.

EDIT: I have been doing this problem for several days now on and off and I have no idea how to start...I'd rather skip the hints honestly, as I've been given a few and still am missing a key piece.

Comment: You really should not be having trouble with (1): if the order of $x\in G$ is $p^n$, what are the possible orders of $f(x)$? This requires nothing more than the definition of *homomorphism*.

Comment: What is holding you back?

Comment: So...If I recall the order must divide $p^n$, correct? Which finishes the proof...On the second one, I just don't know how to use surjectivity to show maximality...

Comment: Yes, that’s right; and that takes care of (1). Do you know that every $p$-group is contained in a Sylow $p$-group? If $f[H]$ is not Sylow, expand it to a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $H$; what must $f^{-1}[P]$ look like? (Be careful here: it need not be a $p$-group, but ...)

Comment: It must contains H and, if it unique, we are done since it's inverse would have to be normal...but we don't know it's unique...

Comment: You’re right; I’m getting sleepy and not thinking straight.

Comment: Can we move this to chat for a sec?

Comment: I'd just like to add for the record to those voting to close this question as a duplicate: (2) in this question hasn't been asked in the question that you're proposing this is a duplicate of. (I haven't voted to close this as a duplicate and I discourage such a vote because, for the reasons just given, I don't think that this question is a perfect duplicate. That said, (1) has already been asked in a previous question by @AnthonyVasaturo so I would encourage him to remove (1) from this question. This shouldn't be an issue since Brian has already addressed (1) in the comments above.)